# Swift dynamic cast failed when adding a new View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple iOS test app in swift.  I've added an additional View Controller at the start of my storyboard and created a class LoginViewController: UIViewController  I've set my View Controller to be the custom class LoginViewController and changed the properties to make it the initial view controller.

I also added a simple button which is my segue to the rest of the app.

Now when I start my app in the simulator, it immediately crashes with the following:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x10cc3f9e0:  pushq  %rbp
0x10cc3f9e1:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10cc3f9e4:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x10cc3f9e7:  je     0x10cc3fa1e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x10cc3f9e9:  movabsq $-0x7fffffffffffffff, %rax
0x10cc3f9f3:  testq  %rax, %rdi
0x10cc3f9f6:  jne    0x10cc3fa1e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x10cc3f9f8:  leaq   0xb5109(%rip), %rax
0x10cc3f9ff:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x10cc3fa02:  andq   (%rdi), %rax
0x10cc3fa05:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
0x10cc3fa10:  cmpq   %rsi, %rax
0x10cc3fa13:  je     0x10cc3fa2d               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77
0x10cc3fa15:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rax
0x10cc3fa19:  testq  %rax, %rax
0x10cc3fa1c:  jne    0x10cc3fa10               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 48
0x10cc3fa1e:  leaq   0x36b3d(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x10cc3fa25:  movq   %rax, 0xb4a2c(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x10cc3fa2c:  int3   
0x10cc3fa2d:  movq   %rdi, %rax
0x10cc3fa30:  popq   %rbp
0x10cc3fa31:  retq   
0x10cc3fa32:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

I've obviously missed a simple step, just don't know what it is!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting following error:

swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional

Swift dynamic cast failed

Problem code: I was using CredentialsSetting ViewController every time when connect to different segue

```
 // programming mark ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ----

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

            var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as CredentialsSetting;
            detailController.viewControllerType = self.viewControllerType


    }// end prepareForSegue
```

Solution: to solve this I have added the specific condition to transfer segue for differennt connections:

```
 // programming mark ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ----

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {


        if self.viewControllerType == "donothavepassword" || self.viewControllerType == "forgotpassword"  {

            var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as CredentialsSetting;
            detailController.viewControllerType = self.viewControllerType


        }


    }// end prepareForSegue
```